# rsql-jpa error while searching by one-to-many

Tags: java, jpa, rsql

The project uses `com.github.tennaito.rsql-jpa`. I'm trying to build a filter like this: `refPersonByPersonId.rsysUserByRsysUserId.rsysFRoleUserByRsysUserId.rsysFRoleByFRoleId.froleUserId==304`, and I get the error: `org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.SingularAttributePath cannot be cast to javax.persistence.criteria.From`

If you build a simpler filter like `refPersonByPersonId.id == 10`, then everything is fine.

The structure of the object below is given in json format (what I get at the output from the api).

```
{
  ...
  "refPersonByPersonId": {
    ...
    "rsysUserByRsysUserId": {
      ...
      "rsysFRoleUserByRsysUserId": [
        {
          ...
          "rsysFRoleByFRoleId": {
           ...
            "froleId": 304
          },
        },
```

Maybe someone worked with rsql-jpa and such a problem when a one-to-many query is needed.